# How would I make an drill through/down (child) report work independently ( to be run on its own)?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, parent-child, drilldown

I have a parent report that passes certain parameters and drillsdown to a child report. I ve already set up both reports to run independent , so I have set up the child report to be ran by selecting the parameters and giving the parameters a set of "available values",  however now when i try to drilldown from the parent report, it wont pass the parameters automatically and requires the user to insert them manual as if they were running it independently. How can I fix my report so that it works both wayS?

Comment: When your parameter values don't seem to pass down to the child report, it probably means that the values you are passing aren't listed in the available values.  Can you show the parameter passing code as well as a sample of the data in your available values in the child report?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by making sure that the data passed down from one report to the other matched exactly with the data found in the parameters.